# How to find time complexity of nested for loops that involves logarithms and summation rule?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

So I have been trying to find the time complexity of the code displayed below. I know that the first for loop iterates 'n' times and must be multiplied by the iterations of the second for loop to find the big-oh time complexity. However, the conditions inside the second for loop are confusing me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j = j * 2) {
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

if `j` is multiplied by 2 times every iteration, then the time complexity of both loops would be `O(nlog(n))`. But since `j` stops based on the value of `i`, I assume that the summation rule would have to get involved. My best guess to the overall time complexity would be `O(nlog^2(n)`? Am I right or wrong and why?

Comment: `j=j*2` doesn’t do much starting from 0!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*O*(log *n*) is the cost of the *last* (worst) loop over `j`, so *O*(*n* log *n*) is an **upper** bound.  The question is whether it’s less because the *average* cost is lower.  But it’s not: that only happens for strongly **convex** functions (consider a simple inner loop with *i* iterations, where the average is just a constant factor times *n*), and log is concave.  So it’s just *O*(*n* log *n*) after all.

Comment: so you wouldnt need to use the summation rule of n(n+1)/2 where n is log(n)... I assumed you would since 'j' is dependant on 'i'

Comment: @CosmicCat: For linear inner loops, the summation contributes merely a constant factor *vs.* simple multiplication; for a logarithmic inner loop, it doesn’t even do that.